# Debian 9.1: apt-get autoremove will not remove dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

[image]

as can be seen from the screenshot, I installed checkinstall and it came with lots of new dependent packages.

When I ran:

```
sudo apt-get purge checkinstall
```

only checkinstall was deleted. I then ran:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

to delete the new packages but nothing was deleted.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? Thanks

PS. please ignore the folder ubuntu. it's just a directory name. I'm really using Stretch

**edit1:** output of aptitude why binutils build-essential

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, `apt-get autoremove` is very conservative, which results in the behaviour you’re seeing. While `apt-get install` only considers direct dependencies and recommendations by default, `apt-get autoremove` also considers suggestions (very weak dependencies). This is asymmetric and means that *by default*, `apt-get autoremove` won’t necessarily fully undo a package installation.

Thus in your case, installing `checkinstall` pulled in a number of packages, all of which end up somehow considered non-removable by `apt-get autoremove`; for example, `build-essential` is kept because `apt` (which is definitely necessary) suggests `dpkg-dev`, which recommends `build-essential`. You’ll find relationships of this kind for every package pulled in by `checkinstall`.

To fix this, you can add

```
Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false" ;
```

With this setting, `apt-get autoremove` will find more packages to remove. Since your system is newly installed, it should be safe (by that I mean that the asymmetry mentioned above won’t cause many surprises, because you haven’t installed many packages); but do examine the list of packages it’s going to remove before actually removing them!

Comment: I added the line in /etc/apt/apt.conf and then was able to remove g++ that was installed automatically when installing VirtualBox from Debian Fast Track. However `apt autoremove` still does not uninstall other packages installed automatically like libasan8 that are no longer needed, any idea why?

Comment: @baptx not with only that information ;-). `aptitude why libasan8` will tell you why `libasan8` is kept installed on your system. If that doesn’t clarify the situation, feel free to [ask a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with more details.

Comment: I asked the question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/771812/apt-autoremove-does-not-remove-all-dependencies-even-with-aptautoremovesugge