# How to explain apt dependencies that are not autoremoved?

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

The package `libudev1:i386` is installed on my system.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libudev1:i386
ii  libudev1:i386  245.4-4ubuntu3.2  i386  libudev  shared library
```

It won't get autoremoved.

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

It was not manually marked for install.

```
$ apt-mark showmanual | grep libudev1 | wc -l
0
```

`aptitude` does not know why it is installed.

```
$ aptitude why --show-summary libudev1:i386
Packages requiring libudev1:i386:
```

Neither does `apt-rdepends`.

```
apt-rdepends --reverse --state-follow=Installed --state-show=Installed --follow=Depends,Recommends,Suggests libudev1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libudev1:i386
```

So why does `libudev1:i386` remain installed instead of getting autoremoved? This question isn't about the specific case: I would like to learn a reliable way to explain why some packages remain installed instead of getting autoremoved.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. The package is a leftover dependency after installing then removing `lmms:amd64`. I know how to clean up.

Answer (score 1):

When I started reading your question I thought it might be a variant of [Debian 9.1: apt-get autoremove will not remove dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394329/86440), but your `apt-rdepends` command shows it isn’t.

However, `apt show libudev1:i386` reveals why the package isn’t a candidate for autoremoval:

```
Package: libudev1:i386
Version: 245.4-4ubuntu3.2
Priority: required
Section: libs
Source: systemd
[...]
```

It has priority “required”, so once it’s installed, it won’t ever be a candidate for auto-removal. (This `libudev1` configuration is Ubuntu-specific; the Debian package has priority “optional”.)

To answer your general question, packages aren’t candidates for auto-removal if they’re marked as manually-installed, essential, have priority “important” or “required”, are depended upon, recommended, or suggested by another installed package, are protected from removal (*e.g.* the current kernel), or are held. You can see this in [`apt-pkg/depcache.cc` in the `apt` source code](https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/apt/-/blob/57356d5795ff841ebbacfce63cf48e97fde80682/apt-pkg/depcache.cc#L2216).