# apt autoremove does not remove all dependencies even with Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";

Tags: debian, apt

Like mentioned as comment to an answer [Debian 9.1: apt-get autoremove will not remove dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394329/debian-9-1-apt-get-autoremove-will-not-remove-dependencies/394458#comment1473313_394458),
I added the line `Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";` in /etc/apt/apt.conf and then was able to remove g++ that was installed automatically when installing VirtualBox from Debian Fast Track (I am using Debian 12 so I had to replace the codename bullseye with bookworm since the instructions on https://fasttrack.debian.net/ are not updated).

However `apt autoremove` still does not uninstall other packages installed automatically like libasan8 that are no longer needed. Do you know why and is there a solution to remove them automatically?

Here are all packages installed by executing `sudo apt install virtualbox`:

```
build-essential dkms dpkg-dev g++ g++-12 gcc gcc-12 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan8 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcc1-0 libcrypt-dev libgcc-12-dev
libgsoap-2.8.124 libitm1 liblsan0 liblzf1 libnsl-dev libstdc++-12-dev libtirpc-dev libtsan2 libubsan1 libvncserver1 linux-compiler-gcc-12-x86 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-common
linux-headers-amd64 linux-kbuild-6.1 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev patch rpcsvc-proto virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
```

Here are the packages removed by executing `sudo apt purge virtualbox`:

```
virtualbox* virtualbox-qt*
```

These additional packages were removed by executing `sudo apt autoremove --purge`:

```
dkms* libgsoap-2.8.124* liblzf1* libvncserver1* linux-headers-amd64* virtualbox-dkms*
```

By executing the same command after adding `Apt::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant "false";` in /etc/apt/apt.conf, these packages were removed also:

```
build-essential* dpkg-dev* g++* g++-12* gcc* libalgorithm-diff-perl* libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl* libalgorithm-merge-perl* libstdc++-12-dev* make* patch*
```

And as requested after my comment, here is the output of `aptitude why libasan8`:

```
i   aptitude      Recommends libdpkg-perl               
i A libdpkg-perl  Suggests   gcc | c-compiler           
i A gcc-12        Provides   c-compiler                 
i A gcc-12        Depends    libgcc-12-dev (= 12.2.0-14)
i A libgcc-12-dev Depends    libasan8 (>= 12.2.0-14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of my answer to [Debian 9.1: apt-get autoremove will not remove dependencies](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/394329/86440) was only to make the behaviour of `apt install` and `apt autoremove` symmetric — the former ignores “Suggests” dependencies by default, the answer explains how to make the latter ignore them too.

In your case, I don’t think there’s an automated way of removing all the packages pulled in by `virtualbox`, because one of them is `linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64`, and that is a protected kernel package (see `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` on your system). It won’t be a candidate for autoremoval until at least two newer kernels are installed, so you need to remove it manually if you want to get rid of it:

```
   sudo apt purge linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64
```

There *is* a corresponding APT option, `Apt::Protect-Kernels`, and you could disable that — but assuming you’re running a kernel matching the latest packages, 6.1.0-18, the headers package will still be protected.

Once that package is removed, the C compiler should become a candidate for auto-removal, and `apt autoremove` should remove most if not all of the remaining packages.

If that’s not the case, you might also need to tell `autoremove` (or `autopurge`) to ignore “Recommends” dependencies:

```
sudo apt -o Apt::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false autopurge
```

Take care when running this — it will offer to remove all packages which are only kept to satisfy “Recommends”, which could well be more than the set of packages installed through `virtualbox`.

Setting `RecommendsImportant` to `false` breaks the symmetry with package installation, so it shouldn’t be set in `apt`’s configuration unless you also disable “Recommends” installation by default (`Apt::Install-Recommends`). For regular desktop use that’s usually not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks but your command contains a lot of packages that I may not want to remove and does not include libasan8 in the packages to be removed. Is there another way to remove it automatically?

Comment: Right, I suspect the problem is caused by the kernel headers, but you’ll probably need to remove those manually. See the updated answer.

Comment: I noticed the problem happens even without protected package, for example if I install gedit and remove it, it will keep the zenity package and `aptitude why zenity` displays "thunderbird Depends x11-utils | kdialog | zenity". Since I already have x11-utils installed, zenity is not needed for Thunderbird. Isn't it possible to make `apt autoremove` understand that to remove the package automatically?

Comment: That’s [a known bug/feature](https://bugs.debian.org/593562) and seems unlikely to be fixed (see the linked bug report for details).